# SonarQube 5.2, LDAP 1.5.1 can't login

Tags: sonarqube5.2

I got this error trying to connect to `LDAP`:

> [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1]
>
> ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::OrgSonarApiUtils::SonarException: Unable to retrieve details for user in

This is my `ldap` configuration in `sonar.properties`:

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword=true
ldap.url=ldap://ip:port
ldap.windows.auth=false
ldap.bindDN=cn=svcSONARQUBE,ou=OU Service Accounts,dc=pad,dc=com
ldap.bindPassword=password
ldap.user.baseDn=cn=users,dc=pad,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=displayname
ldap.user.emailAttribute=userPrincipalName
```

What's wrong with it?